# why does optimx converge to non-optimal points

Tags: optimization, mathematical-optimization, numerical-analysis, convergence

I am using optimx with BFGS method and differ initial points. I have objerved that it converges on points that they are not optima. Does anybody can explain to me how that problem is faced up?
Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Is the problem convex?

Comment: Yes it is. One of the functions I tested was Bohachevsky on 2 dimensions: http://www.sfu.ca/~ssurjano/boha.html.

Comment: Make sure you provide exact and correct gradients.

Comment: In the optimx I have written: gr= grad and at the begging of the code  I define the grad as following: grad <- function(xx){
  x1 <- xx[1]
  x2 <- xx[2]
  gg <- as.vector(rep(0, 2))
  gg[1] <-2.82743*sin(3*pi*x1)   #dif.f.x1
  gg[2] <- 5.02655*sin(4*pi*x2)  #dif.f.x2
  return(gg)
} I did the same wth Hessian

Comment: Sorry, these functions are not convex. You need a global solver for this.

Comment: Could you please explain what do yoy mean by "global solver"

Comment: A global solver is a solver that does not converge to a local optimum but seeks global optimal solutions,

Comment: Ok. Is optimx used only for local optimum?

Comment: I believe the solvers mentioned in the optimx docs are all local solvers, i.e. they converge to a local optimal solution..

Comment: What are you suggested to use instead of optimx?

Comment: There are quite a few good global solvers. E.g. [baron](http://archimedes.cheme.cmu.edu/?q=baron), [couenne](https://projects.coin-or.org/Couenne), [Antigone](http://helios.princeton.edu/ANTIGONE/), and Lindo Global. Some of them you can try out on [NEOS](https://neos-server.org/neos/). Also some of them don't support trig functions.